# A problem with java Object Streams while writing to file

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I am trying to write an Object of kind "HashMap" to a file & recover it when my program run again. But I faced with an EOFException when I try to read that object and the Object is not read from the file. I use the flush() & close() methods when I wrote the object for the FileOutputStream & ObjectOutputStream. Also I create OutputStream & InputStream together for my file.
here is my code:

```
DataOutputStream outToFile;
DataInputStream inFromFile;

ObjectOutputStream writeTableToFile;
ObjectInputStream readTableFromFile;
File tableFile;

public DNS(){
    try {
        tableFile = new File("table.txt");
        outToFile = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tableFile) );
        writeTableToFile = new ObjectOutputStream(outToFile);

        inFromFile = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(tableFile));
        readTableFromFile = new ObjectInputStream(inFromFile);
        HashMap table2 = (HashMap) readTableFromFile.readObject();
        if (table2 == null)
            table=new HashMap(100);
        else
            table = table2;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(EOFException e){
        table=new HashMap(100);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

and here is code for writing object:

```
            table.put(NameField.getText(), IPField.getText());
            try {
                //writeTableToFile.reset();
                writeTableToFile.writeObject(table);
                writeTableToFile.flush();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Regards, 
sajad

Comment: Are both an output stream and an input stream to the same file open at the same time? Is this a good idea? Create an open the input stream when you try to read, then close it. Create and open the output stream when you want to write, then close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file seems to be incomplete. When I look at your code, you're creating the file table.txt and try to read it immediately afterwards.

This ctor:

```
new FileOutputStream(tableFile)
```

will overwrite the file. If your read it afterwards, it will be empty (except the header information from the OOS)

Comment: So thanks. I replaced OutputStreams initializations to the method that saves the object in the end of program & problem was solved. But is it true that OutputStreams & inputStreams shouldn't be used simultaneously in one place for a file to avoid problems such this ?

Comment: Yes, you should ever only have one of them open for any single file at one time.

Answer (score 0):

`EOFException` means that the file is incomplete. So it's either not `flush()`ed or not `close()`ed or an exception is swallowed somewhere.

Comment: Mr! I used flush() in my code. also when closing program I used close(). I saw the file; it is not empty.

Comment: It was empty when you read it because you had just created a new one and not written to it yet.